# Codeigniter - Cannot call function of another class

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am about trying to learn about Codeigniter,
here in this try and error project, i want to call function from another class.

Here is the detailed code:
`controller/admin/dashboard`

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller{
    public function dashboard() {
        $this->load->library("overview");
        $this->overview->method_overview();
    }
}
```

Where, the `overview` is a the filename of `Overview` class that i want to call and the `method_overview` is a function inside `overview` class.

Here the `overview.php`

```
class Overview extends CI_Controller
{
    public function method_overview() {

    }
}
```

And this is the error that i got:

```
Unable to load the requested class: overview
```

Can somebody please give me solution or explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Overview class inherit the property of CI_Controller you just inherit Overview class

So it would be

```
 class Admin extends Overview{
    public function dashboard() {
        $this->load->library("overview");
        $this->method_overview();
    }
}

class Overview extends CI_Controller
{
    public function method_overview() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're calling the overview class as a library, save that class as `Overview.php`inside application/libraries.
In that file, something similar to:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Overview {

    function __construct() {
        $this->CI =& get_instance(); //gives access to the CI object
    }

    public function method_overview() {
         //....
    }
}
```

Comment: according to this http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/creating_libraries.html, i dont have to put my class on application/libraries directory. Do you think i have to do this? @Mudshark

Comment: Straight from the manual: "Your library classes should be placed within your application/libraries folder, as this is where CodeIgniter will look for them when they are initialized."